# Bokeh server is not recognized

Tags: bokeh

Trying to run simple app from Kevin Jolly's Hands-On Data Visualization with Bokeh Packt.

```
#Import the required packages 
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox 
from bokeh.models import Slider 
from bokeh.io import curdoc 
#Create a slider widget 
slider_widget = Slider( start = 0, end = 100, step = 10, title = 'Single Slider') 
#Create a layout for the widget 
slider_layout = widgetbox( slider_widget) 
#Add the slider widget to the application 
curdoc(). add_root( slider_layout)
```

Then tried to start bokeh server:

...\Python_Scripts\Sublime> bokeh serve --show bokeh.py
bokeh : The term 'bokeh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

bokeh info

Python version      :  3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

IPython version     :  7.8.0

Tornado version     :  6.0.3

Bokeh version       :  1.3.4

BokehJS static path :  C:\Users\k S\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\server\static

node.js version     :  (not installed)

npm version         :  (not installed)

Previous post with same problem did not provide working solution, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would strongly suggest renaming your file to something other than `bokeh.py`. Due to the way Python itself works, this can sometimes result in Python trying to load the wrong module.

It's exceedingly strange that `bokeh info` could work but `bokeh serve` would not, since they are subcommands of literally the same program file. If renaming the script does not help, then you can always invoke the server using the Python `-m` command line option:

```
python -m bokeh serve --show app.py
```

If *this* does not work it can mean one thing only: the `python` executable you are running is a different Python environment than the one that you installed Bokeh into.

Comment: Here's what actually worked for me: I'm using anaconda jupyter notebook, instead of issuing bokeh serve command on windows shell, I openned anaconda prompt, and instead of 'py' extension it is 'ipynb': here is the bokeh server messages on prompt screen: bokeh serve --show notebookFig.ipynb
- Starting Bokeh server version 1.2.0 (running on Tornado 6.0.3)
- Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/notebookFig
- Starting Bokeh server with process id: 3944                                                 -WebSocket connection opened
- ServerConnection created

Comment: Note: started Spyder from anaconda prompt and run the same code and saved it as py extension, bokeh serve --show notebookFig.py, this was also successful atempt.

Comment: Right, sounds like you have multiple Python environments as I said. Best guess: you installed Bokeh in a conda env but have some other (non-conda) Python earlier on your system path.